Unable to serve Angular 17 website build with production using Docker
I'm trying to run an angular 17 (node 18) website using Docker and Docker Compose
This is the docker file
FROM node:18-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm i -g @angular/cli
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY . ./
RUN ng build --configuration production

FROM node:18-alpine
EXPOSE 4200
# Remove default nginx website
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
# Copy built Angular app from the previous stage to Nginx directory
COPY --from=build /app/dist/web-site /usr/share/nginx/html

After a few hours of google and chatgpt I have tried running :

"ngingx -g dameon off;
"ng s"

..but none of that works since they are not recognized or not found
Just in case here my section of the Docker-compose file
  angular-app:
    build:
      context: ./web-site
      dockerfile: web-site.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "4200:4200" # Map container port to host port
    networks:
      - cp_network
    depends_on:
      - dotnet-api

I have spent some hours searching for a solution but something is probably missing

i think you're messing up a few things here. if you want to deliver your build artifact with client side rendering and nginx you have to use the nginx docker image, not the node one.
if you want to deliver your page with server side rendering you have use the node docker image, but then you have to use start the node script in your docker command.
if you tell what variant you're trying to achieve (SSR with node or CSR nginx) it should be quite simple to answer your question.

CSR nginx, yeah seems like I have mixed the approaches

ah, ok... CSR fine :-D
give me an hour, after dinner i'm going to write an example docker and docker-compose file and add it as an answer so that your problem is solved.

As mentioned in the comments, the question mixes the way of how a server side rendered application is delivered (via node image) and how static files for a client side rendered application are delivered (via web server, for example nginx).
Be aware that the following files are just a very simple setup for demonstration purposes and that the configuration and naming is close to the setup in the question. For a clean production setup it would require more configuration (like caching in the nginx configuration), better naming (web-site and angular-app are not very good names and mixing them makes it worse) and a more sophisticated directory structure. That said, to get the code up and running you can start with those files:
Dockerfile
FROM node:18-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY . ./
RUN npm run ng -- build --configuration production


FROM nginx:1.25.4-alpine
COPY nginx.default.conf.template /etc/nginx/templates/default.conf.template
EXPOSE 4200
COPY --from=build /app/dist/web-site/browser /usr/share/nginx/html/web-site

Notes:

If you use npm run ng -- build you don't have to install npm i -g @angular/cli globally in your build container. It just uses the local Angular CLI that is installed anyway via npm ci.
I am personally not really a fan of staged builds in docker files for node projects. I would run a node container with a bind-mount to create the build artifacts, saved to the file system, and then do a separate build for the docker image. This gives you the possibility to reuse the same installed node_modules to create the build artifact and use it for other things, like running ng serve or tests in a docker container. But however, that's another topic.

nginx.default.conf.template
server {
  listen       4200;

  root   /usr/share/nginx/html/web-site;

  location / {
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    expires -1;
  }
}

Notes:

Usually in the docker image you want to deliver through port 80 instead of 4200, but I kept it, to keep the setup close to the question.
Be aware, that if you use this image in a production environment you should have quite some more configuration. Especially cache headers and stuff like that.

docker-compose.yaml
version: '3.9'
services:
  angular-app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"

Notes:

Be aware that the example uses for the Dockerfile the default filename instead of the web-site.Dockerfile that was used in the setup of the question. This is just to keep the build configuration more simple. However, I would anyway suggest to always use Dockerfile as filename and if you need multiple of them, splitting them up in separate directories instead of using prefixes.

For this specific example all files should be in the root of a standard Angular CLI workspace.

Build and run
$ docker compose build
$ docker compose up angular-app

Note: You can also use docker-compose if you're using the non integrated docker compose
docker-compose vs docker compose
Unlike Compose V1, Compose V2 integrates into the Docker CLI platform and the recommended command-line syntax is docker compose.


Thanks this has solved the problem, could you share a link to configure the bind-mount, It would be nice to make the angular app (inside docker) to autoreload as when working locally

sure, i can create a simple example repository. but i don't have time left today, so that would take 1-2 days to find some free time. i'm going to share the link here as soon as i created the repo.

I found this - https://jdlm.info/articles/2016/03/06/lessons-building-node-app-docker.html and will keep searching - enjoy your time - thanks again

Your final build stage is built FROM node, but then the comments and file paths start talking about an Nginx setup.  If the RUN ng build step produces a completely static application, then you probably want your final build stage to be based on an Nginx image instead:
FROM node:18-alpine as build
# ... what you have in the question for the first stage ...

FROM nginx:1.25
COPY --from=build /app/dist/web-site /usr/share/nginx/html

The standard nginx image configuration listens on the standard HTTP port 80.  In your Compose setup, you need to make this be the second ports: number as well.  I'd leave the first number unchanged; there's no requirement that the two numbers match.
services:
  angular-app:
    ports:
      - "4200:80"

